# How do I use LIMIT in a codeigniter/doctrine query?

Tags: doctrine-orm, limit, codeigniter-2

I am using CodeIgniter2 + Doctrine2, and have the following query:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("
         SELECT u
         FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Characters u
         WHERE u.fathersId = $key
         AND u.deathDate IS NULL
         AND u.isRuler = '0' 
         AND u.isFemale = '0'
         AND u.useAI = '1'
         AND u.bornDate <= $of_age
           ");
$sons_of_age = $query -> getResult();
```

And I only want to get ONE result, assuming there are any hits.

I've looked at Doctrine documentation about using `->LIMIT(1)` but I have tried putting this into my query in various places, and only get errors.

Codeigniter has some functions builtin to do `$query->row()` but this does not seem to work - I wager because of the Doctrine integration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for method [`Query::setMaxResults($number);`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only) Then you can use [`Query:getSingleResult();`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats), but method `Query:getSingleResult();` throws error if there's no record.

```php
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("
         SELECT u
         FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Characters u
         WHERE u.fathersId = $key
         AND u.deathDate IS NULL
         AND u.isRuler = '0' 
         AND u.isFemale = '0'
         AND u.useAI = '1'
         AND u.bornDate <= $of_age
           ");
$query->setMaxResults(1);
try {
  $sons_of_age = $query->getSingleResult();
} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
  $sons_of_age = null;
}
```